# how to access elements inside a variable named div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var temp = $('#temp');
$('button').on('click', function(){
  temp.html($('#wrap').html());
  temp('.elmark').removeClass('elact');  // error
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<div id='wrap'>
<div class='elmark elact'>R</div>
</div>
<div id='temp'></div>
```

how to access '.elmark' inside `temp` using `temp`?

Comment: Something like `$('.elmark', temp)` would work I think

Comment: @NickParsons, no, of course

Comment: Using `$('.elmark', temp).removeClass('elact');` seems to work, not sure what you mean by "no, of course" ?

Comment: @NickParsons, did you try? write a snippet pls

Comment: @NickParsons, excuse me, you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var temp = $('#temp');
$('button').on('click', function(){
  temp.html($('#wrap').html());
  temp.find('.elmark').removeClass('elact'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<div id='wrap'>
<div class='elmark elact'>R</div>
</div>
<div id='temp'></div>
```

Comment: You should have removed "// error", but yes find() is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the second argument of the jQuery selector [`$()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) to specify the context. This way you'll find all elements which match the selector which are descendants of `temp` (ie the context):

```js
var temp = $('#temp');
$('button').on('click', function() {
  temp.html($('#wrap').html());
  $('.elmark', temp).removeClass('elact'); 
});
```

```css
.elact {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<div id='wrap'>
  <div class='elmark elact'>R</div>
</div>
<div id='temp'></div>
```